# How and from where AndroidManifest file is picked in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, supersonic, tapjoy

I am trying to integrate NativeX, Supersonic and Tapjoy plugins in the same applications. The few I am facing is, that all of these plugins have their own AndroidManifest files, residing at location

> /Assets/Plugin/Android

. And one in

> /Assets/Plugin/Android/google-play-services

How would I know which manifest file will be used with building a project for android?

Because when I run the project, none of the advertisement are getting fired up in the application.

Thanks.

Comment: hi @muttahir .. any luck ?

Comment: @Jeo: Yes, I managed to merge all the content in one android manifest file and for the made the dll files for the rest of the project files. It worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Jeo: Yes, I managed to merge all the content in one android manifest file and for the made the dll files for the rest of the project files. It worked perfectly fine. It was done by great chinese guys. I just had translate his work in english to understand it.